# EndPointDispatcher and Attributes set on the service or service contract

Tags: wcf, attributes, endpoints, iservicebehaviors

I am using WCF and IServiceBehaviors,  and adding EndPointDispatchers.

What I would like to check is that on the EndPointDispatcher is there any way of check to see which attributes have been set on the Service or Service Contract?

The reason for doing this is that if a Service has an attribute then a new Inspector will be added if not then it will get ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way of doing this by using reflection on the assembly, and looking for the attributes within the assembly